# Recover local git branch

Tags: git, branch

I have a git repository with several branches, one of which was a local branch that wasn't pushed to the cloud. My PC failed but I had the .git folder backed up. I restored the files on my disk and cloned the branches in the cloud. I would like to see if I could somehow get git to reference the restored .git folder and recover file changes that were committed to the local branch. Is such a thing possible?

Thanks in advance,
jcc

Comment: Please clarify. So 1. pc failed 2. local repository restored 3. local repository updated with latest cloud commits to branches? or the other way around, cloud repository updated with local branches values? 4. you want to recover the local branch? You recovered it at point 2! And how could you make file changes to the local branch if your PC failed in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, Lingo.

We got hit with a ransomware attack that encrypted all the files on my computer. I had the master branch up in the cloud and a develop branch that had committed changes but I had never pushed that develop branch to the cloud. I had a backup of the source directory and the .git folder but unfortunately the backup of the source directory was when the master branch was checked out so the committed changes to the local branch were not on the disk when I last backed it up. I copied the backups to my computer but the local branch didn't show up with "git branch -a". I restored the local repository by cloning the repository up in BitBucket. I was hoping that there was some way to get git to restore the local branch since all the changes that I had committed to that branch should be in the .git folder. I was hoping there was a way to point git to that folder and get it to restore that branch.